# Android Emulator for a phone with landscape orientation

Tags: android, orientation, landscape-portrait

I developed an android application which works only in Portrait orientation with my own reasons. It works perfect for normal phones. But, [Techno D1](http://bestmobs.com/tecno-d1/) phone (whose default orientation) is landscape shows my app inverted horizontally.

What I want is: Force the orientation in portrait mode AND an emulator for Techno D1 or other phone with landscape orientation.

I locked the orientation to portrait in the java code as:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

I could have done it in the androidManifest.xml file as

```
<activity android:name=".activity.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

A screenshot of how Tecno D1 phone shows my app:

[image]

Comment: try this <activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>

Comment: @Sreekanthss, Thanks for the answer. But, The reason the phone is showing the activity in inverted mode is because I set the orientation to Portait. The reason I don't want to write the code in the manifest is because I have one AbstractActivity (with no layout) which is extended by all the activities with layout. I want to implement this in the java code. I also have many AsyncTask which I don't want to be destroyed and re-created.